# How to correctly print elements out of two dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int Choice = 0;
    int monNum[12][2] = {
    {1,31},
    {2,28},
    {3,31},
    {4,30},
    {5,31},
    {6,30},
    {7,31},
    {8,31},
    {9,30},
    {10,31},
    {11,30},
    {12,31}
    };
    int i, j;


    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 12 (for a month), 99 for all months. (0 to quit):");
    scanf("%d", &Choice);
    for(i=0; i < 12; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < 2; j++) {

        }
    }
    for(i=0; i < 12; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < 2; j++) {
                if ((Choice >= 1) && (Choice <= 12)){
                    printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", monNum[i][j]);
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Current output is as follows:

In month 1 there are 4200816 days

In month 31 there are 4200816 days

In month 2 there are 4200816 days

In month 28 there are 4200816 days

So on...

What it should be:

In month 1 there are 31 days.

So on...

There will be more if else later on to make the functions stated in the first print work, but for now I am lost in space on the 2D array part. If you can help it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the whole last nested `for` loop and replace with `if ((Choice >= 1) && (Choice <= 12)) printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", Choice, monNum[Choice]);`. There is no need to do any iteration at all. That is the point of having a 2D array with an entry for each month - can index straight to that month.

Comment: Hopefully the compiler is warning you that you are not passing enough parameters to match the number of format specifiers here: `printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", monNum[i][j]);`

Comment: Yes that was the case. Though the output is still odd. with the changes

Comment: The output is now In month 1 there are 12 days. with  `if ((Choice >= 1) && (Choice <= 12)){
        printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", Choice, monNum[i][j]);`

Comment: `printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", Choice, monNum[Choice][1]);` should give you the correct output. Here's an example that just prints the array, perhaps it will help. https://ideone.com/E8Firy

Comment: Than you for the help guys. I think I got it now.

Comment: Why do you even need a 2D array? The month gives you the array index 0..11

Answer (score 0):

> How to correctly print elements out of two dimensional array (?)

Save time, enable all warnings

```
printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", monNum[i][j]);

warning: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]
      printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", monNum[i][j]);
|                                   ~^
```

`printf()` is only supplied 1 `int` when 2 are expected.

```
printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", 
    monNum[Choice-1][0], monNum[Choice-1][1]);
```

---

Other issues apply.

Answer (score 0):

There area number of fundamental problems here:

1. The first nested for loop has no effect.  This will not affect the output.
2. The `if` condition inside of the second nested `for` loop should be checking to see if the month number stored in `Choice` matches a month element in the table (i.e. `Choice == monNum[i][0]`).
3. The nested for loop (`for(j=0; j < 2; j++)`) is not needed and should be removed.
4. The `printf` statement should have three arguments (i.e. `printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", monNum[i][0], monNum[i][1]);`).

In short, the code modified to the following will produce the desired output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int Choice = 0;
    int monNum[12][2] = {
    {1,31},
    {2,28},
    {3,31},
    {4,30},
    {5,31},
    {6,30},
    {7,31},
    {8,31},
    {9,30},
    {10,31},
    {11,30},
    {12,31}
    };
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 12 (for a month), 99 for all months. (0 to quit):");
    scanf("%d", &Choice);

    for(i=0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (Choice == monNum[i][0]){
            printf("In month %d there are %d days\n", monNum[i][0], monNum[i][1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```